# Maintain same session in html5/jquery

Tags: jquery

I had a HTML5 + Jquery code to send HTTP POST to server to retrieve the data. First of all, Client apps need to perform login through Jquery + json. Then, client need to use the same session to call the web services to retrieve the data.

Can anyone advice me/ provide me an example on how to maintain/store session using js/jquery and html5 only?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or may be go the cookie-less session approach; if your login json has the capability to disperse a token...

Comment: may be this might help [link](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/html5_webstorage.asp)

Answer (score 1):

To maintain session, the browser needs a session cookie (created server side). YOu may need to do the authentication without ajax.

Comment: can you provide me an simple example?